# How test Amazon QLDB in Java with Junit

Tags: junit5, spring-boot-test, amazon-qldb

I'm trying to create unit tests for my repository, but I can't mock the `QLDBDriver`. I've searched for information, but I couldn't find anything for Java, and everything I've tried hasn't worked.

For example I'm trying to test this method.

```
public DataQLDB getDataById(String id) {
   return qldbDriver.execute(transactionExecutor -> {
       try {
           IonString ionId = ionSystem.newString(id);
           Result result = transactionExecutor.execute(
                "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE id = ?", ionId
           );
           Iterator<IonValue> it = result.iterator();
           if (!it.hasNext()) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException(id);
           }
           return mapper.readValue(it.next(), DataQLDB.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new TransactionExecutorException(e.getMessage());
        }
   });
}
```

I Mock the `QldbDriver` and `injectMock` in the `qldbRepository` but only verify the driver execute. I need to test inside the `qldbDriver.execute`. How can I mock the **transactionExecutor.execute**?